# Android: A good looking (standard) settings menu

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm trying to get my app to blend in as much as possible with the "standard" with the rest of my android device. It's a stand-alone app, not integrated with the OS or anything, I just want it to look familiar.

The area I'm interested in is the "settings" screen. If I look at Android's standard settings screen, it's well spaced, perfect font size, with neat pin stripes between the menu items.

How do I do that? Is that a ListView? Is it done with a regular LinearLayout?

I would love to be able to replicate the look & feel in my app. Can anybody assist?

[image]

And it's not just the Adroid OS. it's most of the "professional" apps out there:

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Great question. This is the first result on google, is very well edited and helped me. People often don't realize great questions are as important as great answers. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Actually, this is directly part of the Android source code, so I would strongly advise you to take a look in its structure. See the [Android Settings tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) for more info.

Settings are created from the `SettingsActivity` (which extends the `PreferenceActivity`, you might want to look this too), which in their turn have their layout based on the following xml files:

- [preferences.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/preference.xml)
- [preference.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/layout/preferences.xml)

Things are quite strongly interlocked so it needs some reading...

Comment: Wow ok, thanks for the links. So no easy way then to replicate the same efftect then.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK its a ListView. by implementing a custom ListView, you can achieve similar effect.

Moreover, you'll have to follow the `Icon Design Guidelines` to create such icons for ListView rows

Comment: Thanks, are you saying I should create a custom widget? There's no standard one I can re-use? Or are you saying that I can just use a listview, but add my own list items. I'm not too worried about the icons for now, just the text. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I am saying about providing a ListView with custom adapters. in those adapters, you can decide how your row looks.

Comment: Thanks, Sheikh. How would I supply the list items? From an xml file or can I hardcode it in the original layout xml? Or should it be done programatically?

Comment: I just link you to one of my blog posts which has an example of custom list adapter, you can find where i have put data source and how I have customised each of the row. That maybe helpful to you. Find it here: http://goo.gl/tUzNN

Comment: Thanks again Sheikh - very sophisticated but I think an overkill to what I need. I'll keep it bookmarked, though!

Comment: Sure! That was just an example of how you can customise each row. IF not required, one can always have only one layout for all the rows (As in your case, perhaps).